# Plymouth not asking for LUKS password without ESC in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, luks, plymouth

On Ubuntu 22.04 and BGRT plymouth theme, the plymouth turns black. The ESC key shows me that I need to enter the LUKS password of my home partition. Entering ESC key again shows my plymouth with a password prompt visible.

Strangely, when I remove the `quiet` kernel command from the grub settings, the plymouth prompts my LUKS password correctly, but with the `quiet` kernel command included it is not working as expected, forcing me to press ESC.

I am not using an NVidia or AMD driver.

Any idea how to fix this?